# Shell script call with current dir as first parameter and shell script as second

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I sometimes see this pattern in installation instructions:

```
sh ./ poky-<...>-2.1.1.sh
```

Note the first parameter, `./`.

How does this method of calling `sh` compare to the following?

```
sh ./poky-<...>-2.1.1.sh
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ there's a space after the `/`? It would be an error if there was.

Comment: The first is invalid. Please check what was written and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Might be a formatting error in the pdf with the installation instructions. Thought I saw this before, but well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typographical error in the instructions that you are reading.

```
sh ./ script
```

This would try to run the script called `./` with the string `script` as its first command line argument. This will fail (or at least do nothing).

If you see this *particular* typographical error again, just remove any space between the `./` and the name of the actual script.